# Windows + F (Ctrl + F) is not working in Explorer, but works in browsers?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

The Find functionality for Windows 7 Explorer has suddenly stopped functioning.

All i get is an error message.[image]

Any ideas which `.exe` got corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Search can be "turned on and off" via the | Control Panel | Programs and Features | Turn Windows Feature On and Off | , in there it is called "Windows Search". I would try remove, then let it finish, then reboot,  then add it back, then reboot again.

**Scratch this.**
Before that, and depending on how I felt, I would get into Services .  | Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Services | and check for the windows search service, and see how it is doing.  **OOPs, that is off**, and the search is still working. that service executable is searchindexer.exe